# Is it possible to put different fields into one select form or combox in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if it is possible to put data of different fields in a same row from the same table into select option or combobox in php. I will attach the table below

```html
mysql> select * from item;
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+----------+--------+
| itemcode | modelnum     | item_abb                                                              | qty | price  | spcredit | spcash |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+----------+--------+
| 2        | P9269-12+6BH | Scholer Ma. Theresa Chandelier 2Layers w/ Maroon Crystals 12+6L DK CH |   2 | 230000 | 138000   | 115000 |
| 4        | P9269-12+6CH | Scholer Ma. Theresa Chandelier 2Layers w/ Blue Crystals 12+6L CH      |   0 | 230000 | 138000   | 115000 |
| 5        | P9344-8BH    | Scholer Ma. Theresa Chandelier w/ Maroon Crystals DK CH               |   1 | 90000  | 54000    | 45000  |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+--------+----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

for example for Scholer Ma. Theresa Chandelier 2Layers w/ Maroon Crystals 12+6L DK CH it's price will be in a select option having 230000, 138000 and 115000 in it.

[image: looks like this]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want the data from those 3 fields in 1 result? if so, what format would you want? Or do you just want to make a dropdown-menu with those 3 options? Please add an desired result

Comment: I want to make a drop down menu with with options from 3 fields price, spcredit and spcash. is it possible? @Shogunivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should create a dropdown with the different options

```
echo '<select>
        <option>' . $result['price']  . '</option>
        <option>' . $result['spcredit']  . '</option>
        <option>' . $result['spcash']  . '</option>
     </select>';
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/772959

Comment: I'm not sure how your `$result` array looks so i assumed something like this. If this isn't correct, please add your php script to your question

Comment: is the selected option become automatically the value by this way?

Comment: if your result array contains the value, yes.

Comment: I'm using $rowres array it works. . . but I don't know how to work with the values here. . thank you

Comment: `echo"<td><select name='price' class='field' style='width:100px;' value=''>";
       echo"<option>".$rowres['price']."</option>";
       echo"<option>".$rowres['spcredit']."</option>";
       echo"<option>".$rowres['spcash']."</option>";
       echo"</select></td>";` I Left the value=' ' is it ok?

Comment: can you `var_dump` your `$rowres` array and post that

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT mysql funciton

```
select item_abb, CONCAT(price, ", ",spcredit, ", ",spcash) as price from item;
```